# Convert Sql to MonogoDb

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

how can i write this sql in monogb query

```
select distinct(Users.id)
,userName,gender
,displayPic
,dob
,aboutUser
,jobTitle
,company
,school
,dontShowAge
,makeDistanceInvisible
, isUserVerified
, (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y')) as age
, ( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( locLattitude ) ) * cos( radians( locLongitude ) - radians(?) ) + sin ( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( locLattitude ) ) ) ) as distance,religion.religion_name 
FROM Users 
INNER JOIN religion 
ON(Users.religion = religion.id) 
WHERE Users.displayPic <> 'NULL' 
AND gender = ? 
AND showMeTinder = '1' 
AND Users.id <> ? 
AND ( ( 
     select count(pairID) 
     from Swipe 
     where senderID = ? 
     AND receiverID = Users.id) = 0 
     AND ( ( select count(pairID) from Swipe where receiverID = ? 
     AND senderID = Users.id 
     AND NOT (swipeType = 'like' OR 'superlike') ) = 0 ) ) 
LIMIT 10
```

Here is the MongoDB code I wrote

```
let aggregate = [
            { $match: { userID: { $ne: data.userID }, userName: { $ne: "" }, userName: { $ne: undefined } } },
            { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0, userID: 1, pairid : {
                        $cond: { if: { $gte: ["$userID", data.userID] }, then: { $concat: [ data.userID, "$userID" ] }, else: { $concat: [ "$userID", data.userID, ] } }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: swipeCollection,
                    localField: 'pairid',
                    foreignField: "pairID",
                    as: "data"
                }
            },
            { $unwind: "$data" },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0, userID : 1, "data.swipeType": 1,
                }
            },
            { $limit: 3 },
        ]
```

the issue here is that it return swipe data

what am trying to solve is get data from user collection then check it in swipe collections then return the combination of both user and swipe and the user collection data might not be present in swipe

Thanks

Comment: You would need to write an aggregation query.

Comment: the aggregation query I wrote is not working

Comment: I would add the attempt you made an an aggregation query to the question. You're more likely to get help troubleshooting your existing attempt than basically asking people to do the translation for you.